# How to set placeholder values in properties file in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Below is application.properties file

```
app.not.found=app with {0} name can not be found.
```

How to replace {0} with some value in spring?

I am using below code to read properties file values.

```
env.getProperty("app.not.found")
```

but not getting how to set placeholder values.

Comment: How are you trying to set the value if the placeholder? When starting the application through a command line argument? through an externalized property file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `MessageFormat.format(String pattern, Object ... arguments)`. It accepts an array in second parameter, which will  replace 0, 1 , 2 ... sequentially.

```java
MessageFormat.format(env.getProperty("app.not.found"), obj)
```

obj will replace {0} in your string.

Comment: Worked. Thanks Nitin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
@Value( "${app.not.found}" )
private String appNotFound;

System.out.println("Message:"+appNotFound);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this code in in appconfig.java//you can give any file name

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {

        var source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasenames("messages/label")//messages is a directory name and label is property file.;
        source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);

        return source;
    }
}
```

2. Then, use this code to get instance of message source which will be bind from AppConfig.java

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

3. String placeDetails =

```
messageSource.getMessage(code,
                        `enter code here`    Array.Of("pass here value"), new Locale(locale.toLowerCase()));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can modify your application.properties like that:

```
app.not.found=app with ${name} name can not be found.
```

you can use a system property  (-Dname=Test) to replace the placeholder:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {


@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @Value("${app.not.found}")
    private String prop;

    @PostConstruct
    private void pc() {
        System.out.println(prop); //Prints "app with Test name can not be found."
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```