# Regex pattern to replace the wrong placeholders with blank

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace a String which contains of placeholders which should only consists on digit.

For ex - `this is the test string {0} with correct placeholder {1}.`

Valid placeholders - {digits}
Invalid Placeholders - alphanumeric, empty, digit with whitespace, character with whitespace

Can anyone help me with a regex. I tried this but its not working -

```
\{((([^0-9]).+?)|(.([^0-9])+?))\}
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: `\{[0-9]+?\}` ?

Comment: You don't need to apply your logic. Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56663908/11338849

Comment: Try `\{(?!\d+\})[^{}]*\}`

Comment: Hello Wiktor, this works, Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\{(?!\d+\})[^{}]*\}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/85HQaK/1)

**Details**

- `\{` -  a `{` char
- `(?!\d+\})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 1 or more digits and then a `}` char immediately to the right of the current location
- `[^{}]*` - 0 or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `\}` - a `}` char.